# Original Chinese version of the mango poem

Tags: poetry

I was reading an [article](http://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-35461265) about mango's cultural significance in modern Chinese history. It mentioned about the following poem which was translated from Chinese:

> Seeing that golden mango / Was as if seeing the Great Leader Chairman
>   Mao!
>
> Standing before that golden mango / Was just like standing beside
>   Chairman Mao!
>
> Again and again touching that golden mango: / the golden mango was so
>   warm!
>
> Again and again smelling the mango: / that golden mango was so
>   fragrant!

I searched on Google and Baidu but couldn't find the original poem. Does anyone know the original verse?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This poem came from Page 6 of Renmin Ribao (Aug 10, 1968). The title was "金色的芒果" (*Golden Mango*) and the author was 鼓兵. The bold lines denote the cited part.

> #### 金色的芒果
>
> 鼓兵
>   首都工农毛泽东思想宣传队的同志们，为了使全市工农兵都能迅速地看到毛主席送的芒果，特在清华园扎了一座彩台，将一颗芒果放在上面。几天来，首都工农兵群众，排着整齐的队伍，敲锣打鼓地来到清华园，瞻仰这颗芒果……
>   　　金色的芒果啊，
>   　　放在红色的彩台上，
>   　　金色的芒果啊，
>   　　闪耀着红太阳的光芒。
>   　　千万支队伍在迎着芒果走来，
>   　　千万支歌曲在对着芒果高唱。
>   　　千万双眼睛在注视着芒果，
>   　　千万颗红心在激烈地跳荡。
>   　　**见到那金色的芒果啊，
>
>   　　就好象见到了伟大领袖毛主席；
>
>   　　站在那金色的芒果面前啊，
>
>   　　就好象站在毛主席身旁。
>
>
>   　　一次又一次地摸着那金色的芒果啊，
>
>   　　金色的芒果多么暖！
>
>   　　一次又一次地闻着那金色的芒果啊，
>
>   　　金色的芒果多么香！**
>   　　多少人手捧芒果眼望中南海，
>   　　幸福的热泪簌簌淌；
>   　　多少人面对芒果表决心，
>   　　誓言滚滚震天响：
>   　　“毛主席啊！
>   　　我们永远跟着您干革命，
>   　　海枯石烂心不变，
>   　　任何困难无阻挡。”
>   　　“毛主席啊！
>   　　为了捍卫您的革命路线，
>   　　我们刀山敢上；
>   　　为了夺取无产阶级文化大革命的全面胜利，
>   　　我们火海敢闯。”
>   　　“毛主席啊！
>   　　我们一定认真读您的书，
>   　　活学活用您伟大的思想，
>   　　我们一定贯彻您的指示，
>   　　一丝一毫不走样。”
>   　　…………
>   　　金色的芒果啊！
>   　　放在红色的彩台上。
>   　　金色的芒果啊！
>   　　闪耀着红太阳的光芒。

Comment: Thank you very much. I was hoping it would rhyme. Maybe I just have no sense for poetry.

Comment: @Fabricator you're welcome :) But don't expect too much. During the cultural revolution, 知识分子 (scholars) were deemed as 臭老九, the "stinking ninth", (almost) the lowest level of the society. So, no one except Mao and his allies dare to show off knowledge on poetry . . .

Answer (score 2):

The poem is from a 2007 article by Freda Murck, who cites the Renmin ribao, 10 August 1968. Unfortunately, I don't have access to rmrb here.  The BBC story is highly confused, you should consult Murck's article for a clearer picture.  If you don't have access to jstor, there is [a 2010 article](http://www.ames.cam.ac.uk/faculty/publications/chau/chau-maos-travelling-mangoes.pdf) on Adam Chau's webpage that is a slightly different take, and without any samples of doggerel verse